# Method for determining frequent co-occurrence

Tags: clustering, recommender-system

Given a set of purchase records, I would like to find out which products are often bought together. Is logistic PCA a sensible method to accomplish that? Are there any clustering methods for that purpose?
I would appreciate any pointers to methods that can help with that.

Answer (score 3):

This is often called „[market basket analysis](https://pbpython.com/market-basket-analysis.html)“ or association mining. The idea is to find co-occurance of purchased products. There are many good [tutorials/solutions/packages](https://goldinlocks.github.io/Market-Basket-Analysis-in-Python/) out there, so it should be easy for you to get a good start.

Answer (score 1):

Determining pairs of products which are frequently bought together is different from clustering. For example, if products A and B are often bought together and products B and C as well, it's possible that A and C would belong to the same cluster even though A and C are not frequently bought together. There's no transitivity, so in general it's not a very good case for clustering, as opposed to "similar products" for instance.

If the goal is actually "frequently bought together", it can be done directly from a matrix of cooccurrences using joint frequency directly, or using a measure of statistical association such as [Pointwise Mutual Information](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointwise_mutual_information). The latter takes into account the conditional probabilities, i.e. if product A is often bought with product B but product B is also frequently bought with many other products, it will have a lower PMI than some pair of products which is less frequent but more "exclusive".